# Is it possible to design a function from input() and assign a variable to that function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the title but I'm not sure how else to word it. Anyway I'm just starting to learn Python and ran into this problem. I'm trying to assign a variable to a function call, where the function contains **input()**

Unfortunately this never assigns anything to the variable `a`

```
def question(letter):
    input(letter + '? ')

a = question('a')
print(a)
```

So I guess my real question is, why doesn't that work? Why doesn't it assign the user input to the variable `a`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're just starting to learn Python, you should take the time to actually learn it instead of simply asking for answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to `return` the user input. Right now the user input is captured nowhere.

```
def question(letter):
    return input(letter + '? ')

a = question('a')
print(a)
```

Comment: Any idea why the downvote?
I am not a native english speaker so not sure if there is any mistake in the way this is conveyed, but I am sure the answer doesn't states anything incorrect.